# Linq merge statement needed

Tags: linq-to-objects

Hi I would like a Linq statement to Convert `List<IQueryable<Object>>` to a `List<Object>`
I am returning a `List<IQueryable<Object>>` so I can use where on the Iquerable part but I can figure that out on my own "I Hope". If the question is too vague I can give you more details if needed.

This is the best I can explain it. I run a for loop and each iteration I get an `IQuerable<ITagLink>` now I tried to union it but it does'nt work cos each iteration is a different type i.e. a different objects but it implements ITaglink but this is not important.
I decieded to add this to a list. Now I have a list of `IQuerable<ITagLink>` but I would rather have each ITaglink in the `List<IQueryable<ITagLink>>` placed in another `list<ITagLink>` but I would like a linq statement to do this. P.S I'm not sure what flattening is but I'm gonna google it now.

Comment: You can do something like `List<Object> list = iqueryableList.ToList<Object>();` but I doubt that's really what you want. You should exlain in more detail.

Comment: This is not merging, but flattening rather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want all of the `object`s from all the `IQueryable<object>`s, right?

```
list.SelectMany(x => x);
```

If you *really* need that to be a `List<object>`, add `.ToList()`

Comment: +1. To make it clearer, here the definition of IQuaryable<T>: public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable. So if the question is to flatten the enumerable of enumerables then using SelectMany is the most elegant way to go.